# send json data through a post call by using rest template from spring

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I keep getting an error saying that this is not valid json data and keep getting error 400. I don't think the implementation I have is formatting data properly. 
Goal: trying to make a post call using a rest template, by passing in JSON data as the body. It seems that when converting from map to json data, it isn't properly converted to json.

```
public void GetJsonData(String name, String city) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("api_key", apikey);



map.put("venue_queries", "[{'name':'"+name+"', 'location': {'locality': '"+city+"'}}]");

        try {
            String resp = GlobalHelper.calltestService(RestServicesUrl, map);
            System.out.println(resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public String calltestService(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(data));
        try {
            response = rest.postForEntity(url, gson.toJson(data), String.class);
            System.out.println(response.getBody()); 
            System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
            return response.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error in post entity");
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, your resulting JSON is not valid

```
{
    "venue_queries": "[{\u0027name\u0027:\u0027yo\u0027, \u0027location\u0027: {\u0027locality\u0027: \u0027Solares\u0027}}]",
    "api_key": "asfasdfasfdasdfasdfa"
}
```

you JSON is not valid because GSON escapes the HTML characters by default and put the single quotes as the equivalent unicode char code U+0027

if you disable the [Gson HTMLEscaping](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping%28%29)

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.disableHtmlEscaping();
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

you will get

```
{
    "venue_queries": "[{'name':'yo', 'location': {'locality': 'Solares'}}]",
    "api_key": "asfasdfasfdasdfasdfa"
}
```

anyway, your JSON is still incorrect.

You have to fix your `venue_queries` key content int the map `using double quotes` `"`

```
map.put("venue_queries", "[{\"name\":\""+name+"\", \"location\": {\"locality\": \""+city+"\"}}]");
```

then your resulting JSON will be valid

```
{
    "venue_queries": "[{\"name\":\"yo\", \"location\": {\"locality\": \"Solares\"}}]",
    "api_key": "asfasdfasfdasdfasdfa"
}
```

Tes snippet

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String apikey = "asfasdfasfdasdfasdfa";
        map.put("api_key", apikey);
        String name = "yo";
        String city = "Solares";
        map.put("venue_queries", "[{\"name\":\""+name+"\", \"location\": {\"locality\": \""+city+"\"}}]");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(map);
        System.out.println("Resulting JSON:" + json);
        map = gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
        System.out.println("Resulting map values:");
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + ", value:" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It helps a lot. Another question is this a good way of typing json manually and sending it to a post call or is there a suggestion you can provide?

Comment: Search for rest client in Chrome web store